Movie about kids catching a neighbour murderer
This American-produced movie was stuck in my memory since my childhood, I have seen it probably 8 or 10 years ago. It was very well-produced, that a tv station aired it every month. 
I confused the movie with Disturbia (2007) because they have a similar story. In my movie, kids spot a murderous neighbour and they catch him. What rules out Disturbia is that my movie is released before Disturbia and the movie I have in mind ends in a different way.
In my movie, they also witness the murder attacking or abusing a girl from their house.
I think I remember a scene where the kids grabbed a ladder from house to house and someone went there and found the body hidden in a freezer (there is high a possibly that the body was buried in his garden somewhere and they all digged and found something).
The ending (99% sure of it): the teenagers (or kids) catch the murderer and they turn him over to the police, and they get rewarded with money (possibly some good amount). The movie ends by showning them, happy, having fun and Water Skiing (or jet skiing), with this song Pump It for Black Eyed Peas put as background.

You're looking for Clubhouse Detectives from 1996. It definitely wasn't Pump It in the end (the song was released in 2005), but maybe the version you saw was dubbed with it.

Late one night, Billy and Kade Ruckman see their neighbor, Michael Chambers, murder a woman, but Chambers has a story all set to convince their mother Vicky, that it was just a rehearsal scene from an opera. The only ones who can help them find the body in Chambers' house before he moves and gets rid of all evidence, are their friends, Jimmy, Eddie, and J.J., who are determined to find the body before Chambers finds them.

They use a ladder at some point between their house and his and it ends with them catching him, splitting the reward money and then going waterskiing. Here's the trailer:




Er, if you're serious, that's kind of you but there's really no need. It'll set you back quite a bit rep-wise. Besides, having a member around that writes detailed ID questions and actually sticks around to approve them is rewarding enough. ;)
